# Matching two columns in Apps Script / JavaScript with a specific condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on matching a pair from a list of names in Apps Script but there's a condition attached to it which I'm trying to figure out.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Names1</th>
<th>Names2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Glen</td>
<td>Adam</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Matthew</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mitch</td>
<td>Damien</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Daryl</td>
<td>Jason</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Steve</td>
<td>Shane</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ricky</td>
<td>Stuart</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the Google sheets link explaining the input and the expected output - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nwu5j2ae_NQAmNQ5WlC-etd12lYMr4FDNKt3iAIjq4w/edit?usp=sharing

*Checkout inline comments in cells A2 and D1*

In the above example, Glen from Names1 column is mapped to Adam in Names2 column. I wish to write a randomization matching code where Glen gets mapped with every other person from Names1 and Names2 column without any repeating matches. This is what I have tried so far -

**Method 1:**
Use a simple randomize() function but repeating matching occurs at a higher frequency

**Method 2:**
Using a custom shuffle function

```
function shuffleArray(range) {
     var i,j,temp;
     for (i=range.length-1; i>0; i--) {
         j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
         temp = range[i];
         array[i] = array[j];
         array[j] = temp;
     }
     return range;
}
```

Unfortunately, this method also shows repeated matching but at a very less rate and it does not do an exhaustive matching with every other person in both the lists.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. Enter textual descriptions in cells to tell what you want in the spreadsheet. Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: @doubleunary - Thanks for the suggestions - I have edited the question and added the spreadsheet with enough information. Please check.

Comment: @TheMaster - I have shared the spreadsheet. Please have a look.

Comment: It remains unclear what your end goal is. You are talking about iterations and matching, but not really telling what you are trying to get. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 0):

You could store what you already get in an array and everytime you get a pair check first if the array does not already contain the pair you found. If you want every possible pair, without duplicates you can do something like this:

```
const found = [];
for(let i=0; i<range.length; i++){
  for(let j=i+1; j<range.length; j++){
    const str = `${range[i]}_${range[j]}`;
    if(!found.includes(str)){
      found.push(str);
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**

```
function solution1() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`Solution1`)

  const personsList = sheet.getRange(`A3:A`)
                           .getValues()
                           .filter(String)
                           .flat()

  const teamsGenerated = sheet.getRange('C3:3')
                              .getValues()
                              .flat()
                              .filter(String)
                              .length

  let newTeam
  if (teamsGenerated) {

    const previousTeams = sheet.getRange(3, 3, personsList.length, teamsGenerated)
                               .getValues()

    newTeam = randomize(personsList)
    while (previousTeams.some((i, index) => i.includes(newTeam[index]))) {
      newTeam = randomize(personsList)
    }

    sheet.getRange(3, 3+teamsGenerated, newTeam.length)
         .setValues(newTeam.map(i => [i]))

  } else {

    newTeam = randomize(personsList)
    sheet.getRange(3, 3+teamsGenerated, newTeam.length)
         .setValues(newTeam.map(i => [i]))

  }

}

function randomize(array) {
  
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }

  return array

}
```

Taking all names from the first column, we see if there are already teams generated. If there are teams found, generate a new team where no player is in the same position as previous teams until found; then insert in next available column. If there are no teams found, insert a randomized team.

Comment: Hi @newaza, thanks for the reply. The reason behind the logic expected is that this runs in multiple iterations and in every iteration, I want a new set of non-repeating pairing for each individual. Request you to check the spreadsheet attached where I have elaborated my query.

Comment: @BharathwajMurali I have updated with a solution to `Solution1` sheet.

Answer (score -1):

> Glen gets mapped with every other person from Names1 and Names2 column without any repeating matches

It is unclear why you want to do this in Apps Script, because a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula should suffice. You can map each name to every other name in a random order like this:

`=transpose( { A3; sort( filter( A$3:A, len(A$3:A), A$3:A <> A3 ), randarray( counta( filter( A$3:A, len(A$3:A), A$3:A <> A3 ) ) ), true ) } )`

See the new [Solution1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nwu5j2ae_NQAmNQ5WlC-etd12lYMr4FDNKt3iAIjq4w/edit#gid=2019459816) sheet in your sample spreadsheet. To get another iteration, click the checkbox in cell `D2`.

> The expected output is just one iteration. Next time when I run the code, I expect to see a different set of pairing for each of the individual without repetition. *`Team 1`*, *`Team 2`*

That sounds like a different question, but you can divide the names in `A3:A` into the number of teams given in `B3` with this formula in cell `C3`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    query( 
      iferror( 
        if( 
          { 1, 1, 0 }, 
          floor( mod( sequence(counta(A2:A)) - { 1, 1 }, { 9^9, B3 } ), { B3, 1 } ), 
          transpose( split( regexreplace( query( transpose( query( 
            transpose( sort( A3:A, if( len(A3:A), randbetween( sign(row(A3:A)), 9^9 ), iferror(1/0) ), true ) & char(9) ), 
            "", 9^9 ) ), "", 9^9 ), "\s+$", "" ), char(9) & " ", false, true ) ) 
        ) 
      ), 
      "select max(Col3) where Col3 <> '' group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0 
    ), 
    "offset 1", 0 
  ) 
)
```

The formula will create a table that lists teams, one team per column, with the names divided randomly into teams, with no names repeating.

See the new [Solution2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nwu5j2ae_NQAmNQ5WlC-etd12lYMr4FDNKt3iAIjq4w/edit#gid=23425810) sheet in your sample spreadsheet. To get random division into teams, click the checkbox in cell `B5`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I need to do it in the Apps Script because this matching happens over an iteration and every time I wish to see a new combination (non-repetitive).

Comment: Please show the desired results you would like to get from the source data you show in the question. Also convert the HTML code into a [markup table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables). Optimally, share a [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).